# Wireless card is not detected on ubuntu and fedora

Tags: ubuntu, networking, fedora, wifi

I'm currently running fedora 27 on an Acer Aspire Switch One SW1-011 (https://www.notebookcheck.info/Acer-Aspire-Switch-One-10-SW1-011-11AN.231024.0.html)

according to that link it's a Realtek RTL8723BS

`uname -a`:

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.15.12-301.fc27.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 22 19:25:27 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When running `lshw -C network` it returns only my usb-ethernet adaptor

```
  description: Ethernet interface

   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@1:3.1.2
   logical name: enp0s20u3u1u2
   serial: 00:e0:4c:36:0d:e4
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.09.9 duplex=full ip=192.168.0.102 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s`
```

`lspci` returns:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 22) 

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers (rev 22)

00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit (rev 22)

00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 22)

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 22)

00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 22)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 22)
```

`lsmod | grep 8723` returns:

```
r8723bs               704512  0

cfg80211              733184  1 r8723bs

mmc_core              172032  4 sdhci,mmc_block,sdhci_acpi,r8723bs
```

I've additionally also tried adding `blacklist acer_wmi` into `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` without any luck

Comment: Have you seen these threads? They might apply to your situation as well: [Wifi not working on Realtek rtl8723be wifi adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772180/wifi-not-working-on-realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-adapter)   and   [How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work) ... I know yours is the 8723BS, but the solutions suggested there could likely address your situation until the upstream bugs are fixed.

Comment: Best way is to report a kernel bug. You can play with custom drivers from strange repos of course, but how safe do you feel using those?

Answer (score 1):

It possible that the hardware is fully proprietary or just block.

`lspci -k`

-k option show kernel driver handling each device as explain in the manual

then

`rfkill unblock all && rm -rf /dev/rfkill && reboot`

That will unblock all things from rfkill that could be block by default

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have the driver module `r8723bs` for the wifi loaded, judging by the the `lsmod` output. Does the driver say what is wrong in the output of `dmesg`?

If you are missing its `/lib/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin` firmware, note that you can substitute `rtl8723bu_nic.bin` as this part of the firmware is interchangeable between the two, and if you don't have that you can get it from however your distro delivers firmware, or from upstream:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/rtlwifi